# Why is NPSP (Nonprofit Success Pack) dramatically slowing down my code?

Tags: performance, npsp

I noticed recently in the performance timeline of an Apex test that NPSP is taking an extraordinary amount of time on the database during our tests at mulitple points. (see picture - all highlighted DB time is NPSP execution) Because it's a managed package, I can't see what's going on. Have others experienced this? Do we know what NPSP is doing that is taking so much time? One specific place I've noticed is that it takes a lot of time upon contact creation, but there are others as well.

[image: Blocks circled are NPSP executions]

Comment: is it in Sandbox or Prod?

Comment: Since it's getting caught up in DB time, that means there's some row lock contention, most likely. Are you following the best practices to avoid [large data skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html)?

Comment: NPSP does householding on Contact creation. Are you creating the Contact with `AccountId` populated? And, to follow upon sfdcfox, are you running unit tests in parallel? (I am the release engineer for the Nonprofit Success Pack).

Comment: Well how else could it prevent you from making a profit?? ;)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal This is in Sandbox. These tests are also running with @SeeAllData=false.

Comment: @David-Reed I get this behavior when I try running simply one unit test in isolation. The AccountId is _not_ populated when the contacts are created.

Comment: I'll also add that this is not even a large number of records. There are a variety of records created in that first block pictured above - 10 contacts, 4 accounts (linked to other records, not the contacts), and 6 custom objects.

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't think this is the issue, though please correct me if I'm misunderstanding. Since this is our Sandbox (Partial Copy) without any of the production data in it, we don't have any accounts with lots of contacts associated. The number of accounts and contacts in the sandbox is <100. It seems like the large data skew issue would be a result of having more data.